# How to render home page after authenticating user in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm using flutter to make a mobile app.
In app.dart, the code controls the main routing.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: hexToColor("#6a1717")),
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationDataState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.state == AuthenticationState.uninitialized) {
            return SplashPage();
          } else if (state.state == AuthenticationState.authenticated) {
            print("now home page");
            return HomePage();
          } else if (state.state == AuthenticationState.unauthenticated) {
            return LoginPage();
          } else if (state.isLoading) {
            return LoadingIndicator();
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And in login bloc handler, yielded logged_in event after log in.

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final AuthenticationBloc authenticationBloc;

  LoginBloc({
    @required this.authenticationBloc,
  })  : assert(authenticationBloc != null),
        super(LoginInitial());

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginButtonPressed){
      yield LoginLoading();
      try {
        final user = await userController.authenticate(
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password
        );

        if(user != null){          
          if(user.accessToken != null){
            authenticationBloc.add(LoggedIn(user: user));
            yield LoginInitial();
          }else{
            yield NotValid();
          }
        }else{
          yield NotRegistered();
        }
      }catch(error){
        yield LoginFailure(error: AppException.unknown(message: error.toString()));
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

When debugging, I checked out that the command "print("now home page");" is executed, and the processor went in home page actually but the login screen does not disapper and the home page is not rendered.
I don't know what's going on in flutter. Please help me.

Login page:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,   
      body: BlocProvider(
        create: (context) {
          return LoginBloc(
            authenticationBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context),
          );
        },
        child: LoginForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Home Page:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your HomePage and LoginPage classes?

Comment: I will add the login page in question post content.

Comment: Have you check the state sequence of BlocBuilder? Does the state stay in `unauthenticated` at the end though it become `authenticated` once?